# Filter (xml-)Data with Where-Object on Sub-Property in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have the following code in PowerShell:

```
[xml]$Xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sequences>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-A</SequenceName>
    <SequenceMeta>
      <SequenceStart>2019-07-23T17:26:54.710+02:00</SequenceStart>
      <SequenceEnd>2019-07-23T17:26:54.741+02:00</SequenceEnd>
    </SequenceMeta>
  </Sequence>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Sequence-B</SequenceName>
    <SequenceMeta>
      <SequenceStart></SequenceStart>
      <SequenceEnd></SequenceEnd>    
    </SequenceMeta>
  </Sequence>
</Sequences>
"@

Clear-Host
$Sequences = $Xml.Sequences.Sequence | Where-Object -Property SequenceMeta.SequenceEnd
$Sequences

Remove-Variable -Name Xml
```

As you see I load XML-Data and then I want to filter it with "Where-Object".
I want to select those "Sequence(s)", where the property "SequenceEnd" has a value.

In this example, the result should be "Sequence-A".
"Sequence-B" should not be shown in the results, because the "SequenceEnd"-property has no value.

I don't know how to select the sub-property "Sequence-End". I tried it like "SequenceMeta.SequenceEnd", but as you see this is not working.

I am looking for a one-liner. In reality the query will be much longer.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
$Sequences = $xml.Sequences.Sequence | Where-Object {$_.SequenceMeta.SequenceEnd}
$Sequences
```

Since the contents within the `Where-Object` script block `{}` are a conditional expression specifically a comparison, a property with no value will yield `$false` and a property with a value will yield `$true` when no comparison operators are present. `Where-Object` returns all objects for which the script block statement is true.

There are some limitations with using your syntax for `Where-Object`, which is the comparison statement syntax. First, you can only reference the first level of properties available from the object you are piping. In other words, you can only compare `SequenceMeta` rather than `SequenceMeta.SequenceEnd`. The code `$xml.Sequences.Sequence.SequenceMeta | Where-Object -Property SequenceEnd` would return one object, but it would be at the SequenceMeta property level rather than its parent, which can be retrieved with the `get_ParentNode` method available to the `XmlElement` class. See below.

```
$Sequences = $xml.Sequences.Sequence.SequenceMeta | Where-Object -Property SequenceEnd
$Sequences.get_ParentNode()
```